# What is meant by box office collection in India?

Tags: distribution, indian-cinema

I would like to know the exact meaning of the Box office collection in indian cinema. Let me explain clearly with an example. Take [this film](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrambam), it was reported in wikipedia that it has collected more than 180 crores. [Some other report](http://timesofcity.com/box-office/aarambam-66-days-collections) said that it was above 300 crores. I’m not asking which is correct.

To whom these collections will go? To theatre owners or to distributers or to the producers?

Comment: If its anything like box office figures from the US or UK - then the money is the total ticket receipts - so it goes to 'everyone' - distributors, producers, theatre owners, according to the various legal agreements between them, in some cases even including the stars of the movies, which are sometimes paid a percentage of the collections.

Comment: This does not seem to be enough to post answer, but according to a Google search, Box Office Collection seems to be the same thing as Box Office Receipts in the the USA.

Comment: @iandotkelly i think you comment is eligible as an answer because as per my knowledge Bollywood box meaning is same as you said.

Comment: @AnkitSharma - too late - no worries though, Jeff Mahaney has given a great version of that answer.

Comment: As I know collections will go to Production House, Sponsors, Director, Producers because other members are already got his amount.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this context, collections and receipts have the same meaning and are interchangeable.

As for who receives the monies, that is based on a sliding scale. The percentage that goes to theater owner and distributor changes depending on how long a movie stays at a theater. The longer a theater shows a film, the greater the percentage of the ticket price goes to the theater.

The theater takes in a small percentage of the ticket price initially, but each week gains a larger percentage of the price. The percentage that doesn't go to the theater is given to the distributor.

As for the distributor and producers, their contract is based off of the non-theater take of collections/receipts and is independently negotiated. (Keep in mind, that some producers are the distributors, some independently finance, and some collaborate.)

Comment: And in recent times even the actors have started to take their own share (in percentages) from the profits.